# Python pyserial object only works when global?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with a arduino from a python script with serial communication. The serial communication works fine when I declare create the serial object globally as follows:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=0) #object to interface with serial, comnumber, baud rate, timeout

def configureArduino():

  try:

    #there are a few lines here to calculate TsMicro I have ommitted for ease of reading

    ser.write(TsMicro.encode('ascii'))
    ser.write('\n'.encode('ascii'))
```

But not when I do it like this inside my function:

```
def configureArduino():

  ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=0) #object to interface with serial, comnumber, baud rate, timeout

  try:

    #there are a few lines here to calculate TsMicro I have ommitted for ease of reading

    ser.write(TsMicro.encode('ascii'))
    ser.write('\n'.encode('ascii'))
```

Anyone know what could possibly be causing the problem?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Are you getting an error message? Is it just hanging?

Comment: Just hanging. It could be do with the how I'm using it. I want to define it within the procedure and then pass it to another function to carry on communicating. I want to do it that way because every time it gets created it restarts the code on the arduino. If define it globablly, it won't reset the arduino whenever I call the configure arduino function.

I guess I should post the relevant in code in full aye?

Comment: Not necessarily the relevant code in full, but a [minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.  I also wonder if this just a timing issue; if you stick a short delay immediately after creating the `serial.Serial` object, do you experience the same problem?

Comment: Putting a delay after creating the object did fix it, thank you. Why does that happen? Surely it does each line at a time and doesn't move on till the communication has actually been set up? I guess not.

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens; I was just guessing based on the change in the relative position of opening the serial port vs. trying to use it.  Glad I was right :).